# Is the rule of parallelism applied here?

Tags: grammar, parallelism

Hundreds of articles praising Bangladeshi government policies apparently by independent experts have appeared in national and international media but the authors have questionable credentials, fake photos, and **may not even exist**, an investigation by the AFP news agency has found.

Is the rule of parallelism applied here? How/why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defective. The structure of the items established by the first two is that of noun phrases serving as the objects of "have". The third item is a new verb phrase. The parallelism is thus ruined.

This is a common mistake even by native speakers, but particularly in writing; we don't often use such structures in speech. Personally, I find these mistakes very jarring.

One solution is to coordinate the two items that share a structure rather than beginning a fake list:

> the authors have questionable credentials and fake photos and may not even exist

P.S. Here's one of my favourite examples of this mistake. Seen at a self-checkout machine at a grocery store. Can you identify the problem?

> Tap your card, insert your card, or slide through the card reader.

Comment: LOL for your example! I was just about to suggest the solution supplied in your edit.